# Yii2 findModel to Array

Tags: yii2

In the **`yii2 documentation`** I found there is a way to convert active record to array .

```
Customer::find()->asArray()->all();
```

But I can't use like this :-

```
Customer::findModel($id)->asArray();
```

How should I do? Please help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should add `asArray()` to `ActiveQuery`, not to the instance of `ActiveRecord`.
Assuming your primary key column named `id`, you should change your model finding code to:

```
Customer::find(['id' => $id])->asArray()->one();
```

Comment: Is this correct (perhaps the question should be 'still' correct)? If I CTRL click on find() in my IDE, it says it does not take any parameters. Cannot find any examples with a parameter either.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#find()-detail
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery

Comment: You are right, @johnsnails . This answer should't be accepted, 'cause right way is: `Customer::find()->where(['id' => $id])->asArray()->one();`.

Answer (score 16):

#### Whole model as array

```
$model = Customer::find($id)->asArray()->one();
```

#### Select specific columns

```
 $model = Customer::find($id)->select('id,name')->asArray()->one();
```

#### Select specific columns as alias

```
$model = Customer::find($id)->select('id,name as full')->asArray()->one();
```

#### Where condition

```
$model = Customer::find()->where(['email'=>$email])->asArray()->one();
```

#### Whole records?

```
$model = Customer::find($id)->asArray()->all();
```

Answer (score 2):

you may use

```
$model = Customer::findModel($id);
$model->attributes;
```